# error passing argument1 of 'Buffer_GetElement' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]?

Tags: c, embedded, buffer

In my code I have these declarations:

```
#define NUM_CHANNELS  3
uint8_t currentByte = 0xAA;
RingBuff_Data_t Buffer_GetElement(RingBuff_t* Buffer);
```

The Buffer_GetElement function is defined in my code like this:

```
RingBuff_Data_t Buffer_GetElement(RingBuff_t* Buffer)
{
    RingBuff_Data_t BuffData;

    BUFF_ATOMIC_BLOCK
    {
#if defined(BUFF_EMPTYRETURNSAA)
        if (!(Buffer->Elements))
          return 0xAA;
#elif defined(BUFF_NOEMPTYCHECK)
    #error No empty buffer check behaviour specified.
#endif

        BuffData = *(Buffer->OutPtr);

        Buffer->OutPtr++;
        Buffer->Elements--;

        if (Buffer->OutPtr == &Buffer->Buffer[BUFF_LENGTH])
          Buffer->OutPtr = (RingBuff_Data_t*)&Buffer->Buffer;
    }

    return BuffData;
}
```

Every time I try to use the following line:

```
currentByte = Buffer_GetElement(uartChannels[ii].RingBuff.Buffer);
```

I get an error saying:

> Passing argument1 of 'Buffer_GetElement' from incompatible pointer
>   type [enabled by default]

Does anyone know why that is?
I've been staring at it for an hour now and can't figure it out. With my luck it's probably some stupid mistake.

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `uartChannels[ii].RingBuff.Buffer` isn't `RingBuff_t*`.

The function `Buffer_GetElement()` is declared to take a `RingBuff_t*` parameter, but you try to pass some different pointer.